# Default value for custom price field to product's price list. Object has Product

Tags: trigger, workflow, custom-field

New at Salesforce. I'm creating a transaction detail where you select the product, then the price field would auto default based on the product's price list (but can be overwritten). I assume you enter some sort of formula in the Default Value field for the Price field? Or would this be a trigger?

Comment: are you using OOTB PricebookEntry feature for OpportunityLineItem, QuoteLineItem or OrderItem?  or is this purely custom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standard way you can't handle this situation,we can use trigger but the value is changeable only after the successfully saving of record.

Otherwise we have to go for custom component to handle this situation.